# Open a file in a tab in vim in readonly mode

Tags: vim, tabs, readonly

I'm aware of opening files in readonly mode from shell using `vim -R`, but how to open a file from inside vim in a separate tab (`:tabe <filename>`) in readonly mode?

Thanks for your time.

Comment: `vim -R` doesn't open in read-only mode? atleast for me. `vim -M` worked.

Comment: `vim -R` works as read-only mode. `vim -M` opens the file with modifiable set to off.

Answer (score 93, accepted):

To open a file in read only mode in a new tab, use

```
tab sview /path/to/file
```

To open the file in the same pane, (without using a new window or tab), use

```
view /path/to/file
```

Note that `tab view /path/to/file` *does not* open a new tab.

Comment: For anyone that isn't looking to use tabs, simply `:view /path/to/file` will open a new buffer with the file in read-only mode

Answer (score 46):

You can open a file in readonly mode from inside `vim`:

```
:view /path/to/file
```

or from command line:

```
$ vim -M /path/to/file
```

Comment: This question is *specifically* about opening read-only **in a tab**.

Answer (score 32):

`vim -M filename` opens the file in readonly mode.

Comment: He specifically said "how to open a file from inside vim".

Comment: Still useful for people coming in from Google.

Comment: @user456584 Only for those who are bad at using Google. This question is *specifically* about opening read-only **in a tab**.

Comment: It's still good you posted that, because I came here exactly for that!

Comment: You can use `vim -R filename` for opening the file in read-only mode (file is modifiable, but not writable) and `vim -M filename` for opening the file with modifiable set to off (file is neither modifiable, nor writable).

Answer (score 23):

Just open your file by using `:tabe <filename>`, then enter `:view`. It will automatically switch to read-only mode.

Comment: I like this alternative; fits my normal workflow for tabs, and easier to remember.

Answer (score 7):

```
vim -R /path/to/file
vim -m /path/to/file
```

Read-only mode.
Modification in text is allowed but you cannot write (no saving).

```
vim -M /path/to/file
```

Even modification in text is not allowed.

Answer (score 5):

Try `:tabedit +set\ noma|set\ ro FILE`; this will open `FILE` in a new tab with `modifiable` off and `readonly` on, preventing you from modifying or writing the file. If you just want `readonly`, omit the `noma` set. Might be convenient to remap this to another command.

Answer (score 2):

Something that works for me:

```
:vnew path/to/file
```

and once the file is opened, give the view command:

```
:view
```

Comment: [user2015258's answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/18395765/712526) does this in one step.