# VIM open file in vertical split in read only mode

Tags: vim

In vim I can open a file in a vertical split by using the command `vs myfile.txt` and I can open a file in a new editor, in read only mode with `vim -R myfile.txt`.

I want to combine these to commands, ideally vs -R myfile.txt, but of course I've already discovered that doesn't work. I want to open the file this way because I have the file open in a different tab and I want to be sure that I don't accidently edit the file.

Comment: This may answer your question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4043650/open-a-file-in-a-tab-in-vim-in-readonly-mode

Answer (score 19, accepted):

The command to *view* a file in "readonly mode" is `:view`. You can split the current window and run `:view`:

```
:vs|view file
```

And here is a variant:

```
:vert sview
```

Comment: Ok. so it does work, you just need to split `vs` and then type `view`. The oneliner `vs|view file` however doesn't work for me.

Comment: Sorry, indeed it does work. I was mistaken because it didn't show readonly in th footer.

Comment: See `:help 'statusline'` for adding the "readonly" indicator in your statusline.

Answer (score 2):

If you want one file to be editable and only one read-only.Then

```
vim writablefile.txt
:vs | view readonlyfile.txt
```